# Laravel Chart need to connect the Database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, charts

I am developing Training Management system so that it has a data table called **registerdetails** and it consist a data attribute called **trainee_division**,
so that consist few several divisions and there are trainees who are in under those divisions.
here is the few divisions
**INOC,
INFRA,
Implementation,
RAN** so what i need is draw a bar chart on x axis using division names on y axis total count a division.

Here is the incomplete controller

```
public function division_details()
{

  $chart = Charts::multi('bar', 'chartjs')

        ->title("Trainee Divisions")
        ->dimensions(0, 500) 
        ->template("material")
        ->dataset('Trainee', [5,20,100])
        ->labels(['OPERATIONAL', 'INOC', 'Three'])
        ->responsive(false)
        ->Width(0);

    return view('registeredusers.divisiondetails', ['chart' => $chart]);
}
```

Here is the view for that

```
`<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

            <div class="panel-body">

            {!! $chart->render() !!}
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>`
```

Here is the relevant route.

`Route::get('DivisionDetails', 'UserRegisterController@division_details');`

These are the packages um using .

provider as

```
`Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,'
```

aliases as

`'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,`

Can anyone help me to fix this problem.

Comment: what does `{!! $chart->render() !!}` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download

```
composer require consoletvs/charts:4.*
```

Add service provider & alias

Add the following service provider to the array in: `config/app.php`

```
ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,
```

Add the following alias to the array in: `config/app.php`

```
'Charts' => ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts::class,
```

Publish the assets

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=charts_config
```

Default Settings

The file in: `config/charts.php` contains an array of settings, you can find the default settings in there.

in controller

```
public function division_details()
    {
        $chart = Charts::multi('bar', 'material')
            ->title("My Cool Chart")
            ->dimensions(0, 500) 
            ->template("material")
            ->dataset('Trainee', [5,20,100])
            ->labels(['OPERATIONAL', 'INOC', 'Three']);

        return view('registeredusers.divisiondetails', ['chart' => $chart]);
    }
```

in view

add this line inside

```
<head>
        {!! Charts::assets() !!}
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        {!! $chart->render() !!}
    </center>
</body>
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank u very much bro